# HTML5 work offline manifest 404 error

Tags: html, caching, azure, manifest, offline

This is error i got 'Application Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (404)'
I got this error on both from azure website that I deploy to and VS2012 development locally           as well. Chrome seems to add cache and delete it.
**Help is highly appreciated.**

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb" manifest="/offline/offline.appcache">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Location Prototype</title>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<p>HEllo</p>
</body>
</html>
```

offline.appcache

```
CACHE MANIFEST

index.html
Content/bootstrap.min.css
```

Comment: Found the solution. It turns out that my locally IIS and azure IIS doesn't like .appcache extension for manifest file so I changed it to /offline/offline.manifest and both servers are happy.